# How do I write an ADL-enabled trailing return type, or noexcept specification?

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-dependent-lookup, noexcept

Imagine I'm writing some container template or something. And the time comes to specialize `std::swap` for it. As a good citizen, I'll enable ADL by doing something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void swap(my_template<T>& x, my_template<T>& y) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(x.something_that_is_a_T, y.something_that_is_a_T);
}
```

This is very neat and all. Until I want to add an exception specification. My `swap` is `noexcept` as long as the swap for `T` is `noexcept`. So, I'd be writing something like:

```
template <typename T>
void swap(my_template<T>& x, my_template<T>& y)
    noexcept(noexcept(swap(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<T>())))
```

Problem is, the `swap` in there needs to be the ADL-discovered `swap` or `std::swap`. How do I handle this?

Comment: this looks _highly_ relevant and contains various informative code snippets down the line: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49107 (just search the page for `swap`)

Comment: FWIW, this issue could also arise if you want the same ADL-enabled behaviour for a trailing return type with `decltype`.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `declval`. For many of the functions that are subject to my dupe-question, this means I could instead use non-trailing return types (though that's unrelated to my problem).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think I would move it into a separate namespace

```
namespace tricks {
    using std::swap;

    template <typename T, typename U>
    void swap(T &t, U &u) noexcept(noexcept(swap(t, u)));
}

template <typename T>
void swap(my_template<T>& x, my_template<T>& y)
  noexcept(noexcept(tricks::swap(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<T>()))) 
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(x.something_that_is_a_T, y.something_that_is_a_T);
}
```

Alternatively you can move the whole code up into `tricks` and delegate to there.

Comment: This is neat because `namespace tricks` can be reused if it has a decent name ;)

Comment: I just realised there is potential for ambiguity, for example when you do this for `std::cos` on g++. See https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/std-proposals/QUkUAinRXig .

Comment: Here's a solution that works without defining a function template: `template <typename T, typename U> using swap_type = decltype(swap(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<V>()));`

Comment: Do we need to write `noexcept(noexcept(expr))`? Isn't `noexcept(expr)` enough?

Comment: @Nawaz: the nested `noexcept` is necessary. There are two different `noexcepts` here: The [`noexcept` _specifier_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) takes a (constant) boolean expression (so `noexcept(true)` is the same as just plain `noexcept`). The [`noexcept` _operator_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) returns true or false (at compile-time) depending on whether its argument is `noexcept` or not. So to say that a function's `noexcept` specifier depends on whether or not an expression is `noexcept` you must write `noexcept(noexcept(expr))`.

Answer (score 11):

There is a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045054/beginning-generically-plus-decltype-considering-local-using-declaration) for return types:

```
// Want to be compatible with both boost::tuple and std::tuple
template<typename Tuple>
auto first(Tuple&& tuple)
-> /* ??? */
{
    // Introduce name into scope
    using std::get;
    // but ADL can still pick boost::get for boost::tuple
    return get<0>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}
```

Using `decltype( get<0>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)) )` isn't correct as `get` isn't in scope.

Possible workarounds are:

- Introducing a dummy template (`get` in my example, `swap` in your case) in the enclosing scope; this includes putting the `using std::swap` declaration in the enclosing namespace, with the drawback of polluting the namespace.
- Use of a type trait: `typename std::tuple_element<0, typename std::remove_reference<Tuple>::type>::type` (actually this one is problematic but for reasons that don't belong here) in my example, and a potential `is_nothrow_swappable<T>::value` in your case. Specializations then allow the template to be extended for other types if need be.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than declaring but not defining a function template, which seems likely to cause confusion, I would write my own type trait (which is what should probably be in the standard library, anyway). Following the lead of the standard library, I would define something like the following:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace adl {

using std::swap;

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_nothrow_swappable : std::integral_constant<
    bool,
    noexcept(swap(std::declval<T &>(), std::declval<U &>()))
> {
};

}   // namespace adl
```

We have to define our own namespace to import std::swap into (to avoid giving it to everyone), but of course, if it were in the standard library that wouldn't be necessary because they can already make unqualified calls to swap.

Answer (score 2):

C++17 has solved this particular use case with std::is_nothrow_swappable: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_swappable