# Determining return type of "generic function"

Tags: c++, c++11, generic-programming, decltype, argument-dependent-lookup

Suppose, I want to develop a generic library which should be usable with number-like types including double and user-defined types. The problem, I'm facing right now is that I don't know how to write the return type of a function template much like this one:

```
template<class T>
auto transmogrify(T x)
-> ???
{
    using std::abs;
    return abs(x)+2.0;
}
```

The using declaration makes this function template's body work for primitive types because these don't have an associated namespace (and hence, there is no ADL). But I want transmogrify to use specialized abs functions in case the author of a user-defined type provides his own abs function. I can't simply use

```
-> decltype( abs(x)+2.0 )
```

because this would not work for, say, doubles since std::abs is not in scope (as far as I can tell). But writing

```
-> decltype( std::abs(x)+2.0 )
```

would disable ADL. But disabling ADL is not an option. Also, the value returned by a specialized abs function might not be of type T but some other type.

Any ideas on how to solve the return type issue while (a) keeping ADL and (b) falling back on some default function (like std::abs in this case) for types that don't provide a specialized abs.

Comment: `#define ab using std::abs; your_template_fn  #undef ab` not sure if that good choice to do

Comment: can anyone comment above thing is good or not?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis and how determine return type of function using this define?

Comment: I guess `-> decltype( abs(x)+2.0 )`

Comment: @Mr.Anubis And where is usage of define? oO

Comment: just before function def, use it too I guess?, btw what happened to your eyes? :P

Comment: @Mr.Anubis sorry. yeah. it's variant, but variant that suggest Dave is better.

Comment: [A similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635939/how-do-i-write-an-adl-enabled-noexcept-specification) that can be solved similarly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a separate namespace, where you can put the using clause.  This prevents the namespace pollution, since the using clause only applies to that namespace.  I would recommend naming it something unique, so you don't accidentally spread it around.

```
namespace transmog_detail
{
   using std::abs;

   template<class T>
   auto transmogrify(T x) -> decltype(abs(x) + 2.0)
   {
      return abs(x) + 2.0;
   }
}

// Then pull it into the current namespace, as recommended by @LucDanton.
using transmog_detail::transmogrify;

// Or if there is a reason, you can forward. 
// template<class T>
// auto transmogrify(T x)
// -> decltype(transmog_detail::transmogrify(x))
// {
//    return transmog_detail::transmogrify(x);
// }
```

Comment: Very clever!  Unnamed namespaces may or may not make this cleaner.  Not sure.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It might, or it might not.  If you use any other unnamed namespaces, they'll also have the using clause, which might not be desirable.

Answer (score -6):

The above answers are good, but the simoplest way i can think of is to use the typeinfo header. it was specifically designed to determine types and constructors of objects.

see here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/

Comment: -1 not at all useful -- type_info is about runtime type identification, whereas a declaration needs a statically determined type.