# Why are is_swappable and is_nothrow_swappable not included in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, template-meta-programming, libc++

I was surprised to discover that `is_swappable<T>` and `is_nothrow_swappable<T>` are not among the new C++11 type_traits metafunctions. They are very useful for propagating `noexcept` for templates and for determining whether it is possible to implement a non-throwing swap for a template.

libc++ rolls its own internal versions: see __is_swappable and __is_nothrow_swappable in [its version of type_traits](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/type_traits?view=markup), and it makes extensive internal use of them but does not make them available outside the library.

I ended up cobbling together [my own version of these](https://github.com/acmorrow/error_or/blob/master/detail/is_nothrow_swappable.hpp) for a personal project, which seem to work but I'm sure its broken somehow.

I am curious about the absence of these two as they seem quite important. Was this feature considered during the C++11 standardization process, or was it just an oversight that it was not included? If it was considered, what lead to it not being incorporated into the final standard (lack of time, implementation issues, etc.)? Is there a defect report or evolution paper discussing this? Any plans to incorporate these traits in C++1Y? Is there an acknowledged 'correct' version somewhere?

Comment: Probably just nitpicking, but should it be a requirement of "swappable" that `swap` return void? Not that I can think of anything else sensible for it to return. I'm trying to be helpful: if you're sure that your code is wrong and I can find some inconsequential flaw, then it doesn't have to have a major flaw ;-)

Comment: Excellent question, and I honestly have no idea. That sort of subtlety is exactly why I'd rather not roll my own :)

Comment: It's a good question, but one thing to keep in mind is that `noexcept` can be used as a keyword similar to `decltype` to propagate exception specifications.  For example, the `std::swap` overload for fixed size arrays has an exception specification of `noexcept(noexcept(swap(*a, *b)))`, which means it's noexcept iff the swap of the individual elements is noexcept.

Comment: @DaveS Good point, but I'm worried about how that interacts with argument dependent lookup? Because in the implementation of whatever function has that noexcept expression, I'm almost certainly going to say `using std swap; swap(a, b)` so that I'll get the ADL swap if it is available, and `std::swap` if not. But I don't see a way to achieve that same effect in the `noexcept` expression, meaning that the test and the code are potentially mismatched.

Comment: @acm:  I agree it would be nice if it were prettier, but a solution is to move the underlying function into a namespace, and put a using clause in there.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635939/how-do-i-write-an-adl-enabled-noexcept-specification

Comment: @DaveS Thanks. I had read that at some point when I started looking into this a bit ago, and my hacked up is_[nothrow_]swappable was the ultimate result of iterating from the accepted answer in that post.

Comment: libc++ appears to use: `is_[nothrow_]move_constructible<T>::value && is_[nothrow_]move_assignable<T>::value` for the `swap` function template.

Comment: @BrettHale: it's a bit of a hack though, because this is only works if `swap` is implemented in terms of the Move Constructors and Assignment Operators.

Comment: I've updated my answer with test results from libc++.  The test demonstrates that it works whether or not the swap is implemented in terms of move construction and move assignment.  The code is open source and found here: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/type_traits

Comment: @SteveJessop Thank you for pointing out the assumption about returning void. If you are interested, I've pushed an update that I think addresses your concern.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`is_swappable<T>` and `is_nothrow_swappable<T>` were never proposed for C++11.  That is the main reason they aren't in C++11.  I.e. nothing gets in without being proposed.

So why weren't these proposed?

Speaking from personal experience, I don't propose anything that I haven't implemented and found useful.  And though I did implement them for libc++, I did not do so prior to C++11 being published.  I simply did not have the time and tools to do so for C++11.  My best guess is that this was true of any one else.

Glad you found these useful.  **You** could be the one to propose them for the next C++ standard!  Seriously!  We need your help!

**Update**

In response to:

> it's a bit of a hack though, because this is only works if swap is
>   implemented in terms of the Move Constructors and Assignment Operators

Here's test indicating how it behaves on libc++'s implementation:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(const A&);
};

struct B
{
};

void swap(B&, B&);

struct C
{
};

void swap(C&, C&) noexcept;

struct D
{
    D(const D&) noexcept;
    D& operator=(const D&) noexcept;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "std::__is_nothrow_swappable<int>::value = "
              << std::__is_nothrow_swappable<int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::__is_nothrow_swappable<A>::value = "
              << std::__is_nothrow_swappable<A>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::__is_nothrow_swappable<B>::value = "
              << std::__is_nothrow_swappable<B>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::__is_nothrow_swappable<C>::value = "
              << std::__is_nothrow_swappable<C>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "std::__is_nothrow_swappable<D>::value = "
              << std::__is_nothrow_swappable<D>::value << '\n';
}
```

Which for me outputs:

```
std::__is_nothrow_swappable<int>::value = 1
std::__is_nothrow_swappable<A>::value = 0
std::__is_nothrow_swappable<B>::value = 0
std::__is_nothrow_swappable<C>::value = 1
std::__is_nothrow_swappable<D>::value = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I suspected as much but wanted to be sure that they weren't 'rejected for cause' before investing more time on it. Working on a proposal to add these sounds like it would be really interesting.

Comment: Since the mod deleting *Beman Dawes*' comment-answer forgot to add his nevertheless valueable statements as a proper comment, I will repeat them here, citing him: *"If you would like to follow Howard's suggestion, and propose is_swappable and is_nothrow_swappable for the next C++ standard, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3370.html for how to go about it.

You can also ask for help or ask others to review your proposal at https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/std-proposals "*

Comment: Per your suggestion, I've started working on such a proposal: http://acmorrow.github.com/swap_traits/nXXXX.html (source is here: https://github.com/acmorrow/swap_traits) and joined the std-proposals group that Beman linked to, which is fascinating reading. I'm hoping to have some friends help me review my draft before sending it to the group. As this it the first time I've attempted anything like this, all feedback, comments, criticism, etc. is more than welcome as I'd like to have what I send to the group be at least somewhat polished.

Comment: Congratulations it made it into the C++17 [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0185r1.html).
I am so happy we have this feature now!

Comment: I need an implementation that uses only C++11 can someone please post it?

Comment: @VinnieFalco:  Here is the libc++ implementation: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/type_traits#L4349-L4442 And I believe this compiles in `-std=c++11` mode.  However it is difficult to implement unless you're the std::lib implementor because you need to alter the signature of `std::swap` to do it.  You have to constrain `std::swap` with `enable_if` on `is_nothrow_move_constructible` and `is_nothrow_move_assignable`.  And you have to perform the `is_swappable` test with `std::swap` in scope.  I don't think there is a portable implementation that you can do.

Comment: @VinnieFalco: I found this implementation a few years ago: https://github.com/acmorrow/error_or/blob/master/detail/is_nothrow_swappable.hpp . I've adapted it to use the detector idiom support proposed by https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4436.pdf and it seems to work well.

Comment: @VinnieFalco: https://godbolt.org/z/jxd5WMKv9