# What is a proper way to implement is_swappable to test for the Swappable concept?

Tags: c++

I would consider "proper" implementation for `is_swappable` to be the following:

```
template<class T, class U = T> struct is_swappable<T, U> : /* see below */ { }
```

`is_swappable` inherits from [`std::true_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) if T and U are [**`Swappable`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable), otherwise from [`std::false_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant).

---

I have tried many things, but SFINAE just doesn't seem to work. This is a particularly nasty counterexample:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};
```

Clearly `A` is not [**`Swappable`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Swappable). Yet any generic solution I can come up with does not properly handle the above example.

A SFINAE implementation I have tried, but did not work looked like this:

```
namespace with_std_swap {
    using std::swap;

    template<class T, class U, class =
        decltype(swap(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<U&>()))>
    std::true_type swappable_test(int);

    template<class, class> std::false_type swappable_test(...);
}

template<class T, class U = T>
struct is_swappable
: decltype(with_std_swap::using_std_swap::swappable_test<T, U>(0)) { };
```

Is there any way to code `is_swappable` without compiler help?

Comment: start with making `std::false_type swappable_test(...)` a two-parameter template as well

Comment: @PiotrS. Woops, that's not why it doesn't work though. Edited in my question and deleted the coliru link.

Comment: And you've taken a look at [is_nothrow_swappable](https://github.com/acmorrow/error_or/blob/master/detail/is_nothrow_swappable.hpp) by [acm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483105/why-are-is-swappable-and-is-nothrow-swappable-not-included-in-c11)?

Comment: @remyabel [Yes, it doesn't work for the counterexample.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04347e234cfaf91b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much thought, the ideas posted by the other answers, and [finding defects in the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793979/why-is-swapping-multidimensional-arrays-not-noexcept) I think I've got the solution that is as close as you can get to a compile-time check for the `Swappable` concept.

It's not pretty. It uses a trick to detect if `std::swap` is used by providing a function with the exact same signature as proposed by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26745591/565635). Then we write helper functions to detect if swapping is possible at all, and whether it resolves to `std::swap`. The last helper templates are used to see if `std::swap` will be noexcept. [This does not use the exact semantics as put forth in the C++14 standard, and assumes the what I think to be intended behaviour of swapping multidimensional arrays being `noexcept`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793979/why-is-swapping-multidimensional-arrays-not-noexcept)

```
namespace detail {
    namespace swap_adl_tests {
        // if swap ADL finds this then it would call std::swap otherwise (same signature)
        struct tag {};

        template<class T> tag swap(T&, T&);
        template<class T, std::size_t N> tag swap(T (&a)[N], T (&b)[N]);

        // helper functions to test if an unqualified swap is possible, and if it becomes std::swap
        template<class, class> std::false_type can_swap(...) noexcept(false);
        template<class T, class U, class = decltype(swap(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<U&>()))>
        std::true_type can_swap(int) noexcept(
            noexcept(swap(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<U&>()))
        );

        template<class, class> std::false_type uses_std(...);
        template<class T, class U>
        std::is_same<decltype(swap(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<U&>())), tag> uses_std(int);

        template<class T>
        struct is_std_swap_noexcept : std::integral_constant<bool,
            std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
            std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value
        > { };

        template<class T, std::size_t N>
        struct is_std_swap_noexcept<T[N]> : is_std_swap_noexcept<T> { };

        template<class T, class U>
        struct is_adl_swap_noexcept : std::integral_constant<bool, noexcept(can_swap<T, U>(0))> { };
    }
}

template<class T, class U = T>
struct is_swappable : std::integral_constant<bool, 
    decltype(detail::swap_adl_tests::can_swap<T, U>(0))::value &&
        (!decltype(detail::swap_adl_tests::uses_std<T, U>(0))::value ||
            (std::is_move_assignable<T>::value && std::is_move_constructible<T>::value))
> {};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct is_swappable<T[N], T[N]> : std::integral_constant<bool, 
    decltype(detail::swap_adl_tests::can_swap<T[N], T[N]>(0))::value &&
        (!decltype(detail::swap_adl_tests::uses_std<T[N], T[N]>(0))::value ||
            is_swappable<T, T>::value)
> {};

template<class T, class U = T>
struct is_nothrow_swappable : std::integral_constant<bool, 
    is_swappable<T, U>::value && (
        (decltype(detail::swap_adl_tests::uses_std<T, U>(0))::value &&
            detail::swap_adl_tests::is_std_swap_noexcept<T>::value)
        ||
        (!decltype(detail::swap_adl_tests::uses_std<T, U>(0))::value &&
            detail::swap_adl_tests::is_adl_swap_noexcept<T, U>::value)
    )
> {};
```

Comment: Fails to compile for me in Visual Studio 2015 with SP3:
error C2672: 'beast::detail::swap_adl_tests::swap': no matching overloaded function found

Answer (score 4):

Building on @jrok's answer, we can tell if an unqualified `swap` call will call `std::swap` by writing a `swap` function with the same signature as `std::swap` but a unique return type that can then be examined:

```
namespace detail2 {
    struct tag {};

    template<class T>
    tag swap(T&, T&);

    template<typename T>
    struct would_call_std_swap_impl {

        template<typename U>
        static auto check(int)
        -> std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<decltype( swap(std::declval<U&>(), std::declval<U&>())), tag>::value>;

        template<typename>
        static std::false_type check(...);

        using type = decltype(check<T>(0));
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct would_call_std_swap : would_call_std_swap_impl<T>::type { };
}
```

Then the definition of `is_swappable` becomes:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_swappable :
    std::integral_constant<bool,
        detail::can_call_swap<T>::value &&
        (!detail2::would_call_std_swap<T>::value ||
        (std::is_move_assignable<T>::value &&
        std::is_move_constructible<T>::value))
    > { };
```

We also need a special case for swapping arrays:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_swappable<T[N]> : is_swappable<T> {};
```

Comment: Are all swappable std-types forever guaranteed to support move-assignment and move-construction?

Comment: @Deduplicator `std::swap` requires `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable`, so all existing code that uses it should be using it with a type that is both.

Comment: Does that really forbid specializations with reduced requirements?

Comment: @Deduplicator Amusingly, we can detect if something that calls `std::swap` in the "proper" way is in `namespace std` I think: do a `using std::swap`-less invokation of `swap` on it, and determine if it works (invokes `std::swap`).  If it does, it found it via ADL.  Which basically gives us a `is_from_std<T>` trait I think?  (`would_call_std_swap<T>{} && can_find_swap_via_adt<T>{}`)

Comment: @Deduplicator No, but specializing `std::swap` is already not a very good idea, so I'm not particularly eager to bend over backwards to support it.

Comment: @T.C. Sure.  But something WITHIN `std` might specialize `swap`, and do so while not `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable`.  It would be `swap` able, but it would fail your test.

Comment: @Yakk Hmm, true. I don't think there's a good way to work around that.

Comment: @T.C. see above: we can write `is_from_namespace_std<T>`?  I guess that isn't good enough, as you could be within `namespace_std` and not be `swap`able.

Comment: So, it finally resolves to an appeal to the committee to add some SFINAE.

Comment: @Yakk Right, limited to the homogeneous type case, no invocation of `swap` would result in substitution failure since the base `std::swap` is always available (and any error in the body isn't SFINAE). I suppose the best one can do is to examine all the specializations provided by the standard to see if any of them is on a non-`MoveAssignable` or `MoveConstructible` type, and if so add a specialization.

Comment: @TC: As of C++14, that list of special cases is still empty. Still not good.

Comment: Shouldn't the special case for arrays only apply when `std::swap` is used?

Comment: isn't it reversed ? shouldn't it be `not std::is_same` since it checks if the return type is `tag` which would mean the type does not get to call std_swap.

Comment: @v.oddou No, the idea is that the `tag`-returning `swap` is a stand-in for `std::swap`; if `std::swap` would have been called outside the `detail2` namespace, it would have called the `tag`-returning `swap` inside.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#include <utility>
namespace detail {
    using std::swap;

    template<typename T>
    struct can_call_swap_impl {

        template<typename U>
        static auto check(int)
        -> decltype( swap(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<T&>()),
                std::true_type());

        template<typename>
        static std::false_type check(...);

        using type = decltype(check<T>(0));
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct can_call_swap : can_call_swap_impl<T>::type { };
}

template<typename T>
struct is_swappable :
    std::integral_constant<bool,
        detail::can_call_swap<T>::value &&
        std::is_move_assignable<T>::value &&
        std::is_move_constructible<T>::value
    > { };

struct A
{
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_swappable<A>{};
}
```

The reason yours doesn't work is that it only checks whether it is ok to call `swap`, not whether it would actualy compile if it were instantiated. That's out of realm of SFINAE (not immediate context).

So I just extended the test with the [requirements for `std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), that is - `T` must be `MoveAssignable` and `MoveConstructible`.

Comment: `std::swap` does perform move-assignment and move-construction, but I can imagine user-defined swap that simply swaps internal pointers, so I would suggest checking `is_move_assignable` and `is_move_constructible` only for `std::swap`, and just `can_call_non_std_swap` for other cases.

Comment: @PiotrS. Good point, but do you have an idea how to reliably tell `std::swap` and other swap functions apart?

Comment: @orlp Yeah, that's what I was afraid of, let's see if there's a workaround :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201703L
template<typename...> using void_t = void;
#else
using std::void_t;
#endif

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_swappable : std::false_type {};
                      
template <typename T>
struct is_swappable<T, void_t<decltype(swap(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<T&>()))>> : std::true_type {};
```

EDIT:

```
namespace swap_details
{
    #if __cplusplus < 201703L
    template<typename...> using void_t = void;
    #else
    using std::void_t;
    #endif

    using std::swap;
    
    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct is_swappable : std::false_type {};

    template <typename T>
    struct is_swappable<T, void_t<decltype(swap(std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<T&>()))>> : std::true_type {};
    
}

template <typename T>
struct is_swappable : public swap_details::is_swappable<T>
{
};
```

Comment: Fails on `is_swappable<int>`.

Comment: i need to add ```using std::swap``` somehow

Comment: It works if  you put ```using std::swap``` above. But then you're polluting your headers