# Correct implementation of is_std_swappable

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

This is not intended to be a duplicate of [What is a proper way to implement is_swappable to test for the Swappable concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744589/what-is-a-proper-way-to-implement-is-swappable-to-test-for-the-swappable-concept) especially regarding the aspect "testing for the *Swappable* concept".

I tried to implement a trait `is_std_swappable`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template< typename T, typename = void >
struct is_std_swappable : std::false_type {};

template< typename T >
struct is_std_swappable< T, decltype( std::swap( std::declval< T& >(), std::declval< T& >() ) ) > : std::true_type {};
```

This works for a `std::string` and `static_assert( is_std_swappable< std::string >::value, "" );` does not error.

Now I tried a type that should not be swappable by `std::swap` assuming an implementation using `std::move`:

```
struct DontMove {
    DontMove() = default;
    DontMove( DontMove&& ) = delete;
};

static_assert( is_std_swappable< DontMove >::value, "" );
```

Result (see https://godbolt.org/z/014kJ2):

- Clang 7.0.0 sees an error here ("static_assert failed due to requirement
  `is_std_swappable<DontMove>::value`").
- MSVC 19.16 does not error. That might happen if MSVC provides a
  non-moving implementation of `std::swap`. On the other hand, using the
  swap yields an error ("attempting to reference a deleted function"):

  ```
  void foo() {
      DontMove dm;
      std::swap( dm, dm );
  }
  ```

Who's right here? Or is my try on the `is_std_swappable` faulty?

Comment: The reason this fails is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744937/4342498) on the dupe.  I used it as a dupe as it has workarounds offered as well

Comment: It's not clear that this "fails". The compilers behave differently here. I tried to reproduce the other solution in https://godbolt.org/z/NQajmI. Same result. So this possibly is not a duplicate of [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744589/what-is-a-proper-way-to-implement-is-swappable-to-test-for-the-swappable-concept).

Comment: Ah, I see. I wanted "Instantion failure is not an error" instead of SFINAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard does not require `std::swap` to be SFINAE-friendly.  Neither does it prevent it.

Neither compiler is wrong.

Comment: I had to learn about SFINAE-friendliness first. Now I will have to look for the implementation of `std::swap` in libc++.