# ADL in constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-dependent-lookup, initialization-list

How can I enable ADL in a constructor initialization list? For example, let's say that I have a `bignum` that has a namespace-level `abs` function. Now I want to write a class `Foo` that initializes its members with the absolute values of the instances passed to the constructor; it should the use namespace-level `abs` if it exists and `std::abs` otherwise:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T _data;

    Foo(T data):
        _data(abs(data)) // I want find abs with ADL here
    {}
};
```

Using declarations are forbidden at class scope anyway and I don't want to "pollute" the namespace. How can I enable the ADL so that it works in the constructor initialization list?

Comment: I assume you have a member of type `T` and not of type `Foo`, right?

Comment: Slightly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635939/how-do-i-write-an-adl-enabled-trailing-return-type-or-noexcept-specification

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can solve this directly from within the initialiser list, by using a lambda expression: it allows you to write the required helper function inline, and that helper function can contain `using std::abs;`.

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T _data;

    Foo(T data):
        _data([&](){ using std::abs; return abs(data); }())
    {}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a free or `static` local helper function and allow ADL to ocurr in there:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T _data;

    Foo(T data):
        _data(abs(data))
    {}

    template <typename X>
    using delete_reference = typename std::remove_reference<X>::type;

    template <typename U>
    static delete_reference<U> abs(U&& x)
    {
        using std::abs;
        return abs(std::forward<U>(x));
    }
};
```

Comment: I doubt that compiles, returning a non-const lvalue-reference to a temporary object.

Comment: @nosid Where am I returning an lvalue-reference?

Comment: @0x499602D2 In your instantiation of `abs<int&>` with return type `int&`, when instantiating `Foo<int>`. `data` is an lvalue, so `U` is deduced as an lvalue reference type.

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper function:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename Arg>
    auto invoke_abs(Arg&& arg)
    {
        using std::abs;
        return abs(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }
}

Foo(T data)
    : _data{detail::invoke_abs(std::forward<T>(data))}
{ }
```

Comment: +1 for making the already posted answer compile, but auto-deduced return types aren't actually valid yet outside of lambda functions, so this fails in compilers in C++11-conforming mode. (I hadn't realised that when I posted my answer.)